Cannot install Python requests on Windows Machine
I have a strange problem.  I am building a scraper, and installed Beautiful Soup, Requests, and so on.  When I run my program, I get this:
C:\Users\CrediblockHome\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/CrediblockHome/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CrediblockHome\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

However, when I run:
pip3 install requests

It says:
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\crediblockhome\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (2.32.3)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in c:\users\crediblockhome\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\crediblockhome\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.10)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\crediblockhome\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\crediblockhome\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2024.8.30)

Help!
Trying to run Python code using requests, but it generates errors.

Run this short code and show us the results import sys; print(sys.path)

Notice that you have two different pythons. One in a PyCharm virtual environment and one in your standard install. I don't know the mechanisms you used in pycharm,  but you need to install it there.

The pip3 you are running is using the built-in Python site-packages while the python.exe you ran is inside the actual venv.  Please see this thread on exactly what you need to do (specifically, run python -m pip instead to use pip).

John, thank you - here are the results:




import sys; print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\Users\CrediblockHome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python312.zip', 'C:\Users\CrediblockHome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\DLLs', 'C:\Users\CrediblockHome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib', 'C:\Users\CrediblockHome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312', 'C:\Users\CrediblockHome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages']



